# facebook share achievement issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to add share the game achievement with following code. however, i got the error during publishing:  error_reason unfinished operation("FBAPIErrorDomain error 100") error_description @"An error occurred during publishing."
any one have any ideas?

```
// Create share photo by path
NSString* picPath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:path];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: picPath];

FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = img;
photo.userGenerated = YES;

// Create Object
NSDictionary *properties = @{
                             @"og:type": @"game.achievement",
                             @"og:title": @"Game Achievement Title",
                             @"og:description": @"Game Achievement Desc",
                             @"og:url": @"http://www.baidu.com",
                             @"og:image": @[photo]
                            };
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

// Create Action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"games.achieves";
//[action setString:@"testtest" forKey:@"achievement"];
[action setObject:object forKey:@"game.achievement"];
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"game.achievement";

// show share dialog
FBSDKShareDialog *_shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
_shareDialog.delegate = s_shareDelegate;
_shareDialog.shouldFailOnDataError = YES;
_shareDialog.shareContent = content;
_shareDialog.fromViewController = (UIViewController *)[AppController getRootViewController];
[_shareDialog show];
```

Answer (score 0):

The game:points property is required for game.achievement objects.  Add this to your properties object:

```
 @"game:points": @"1",
```

For reference, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/game.achievement/

Answer (score 0):

If the achievement is already given to a user, he cannot achieve it again, who result on a didFailWitgError when using FBSDKShareDialog.
Hope it will help